# postgresql won't accept a specific key

Tags: database, postgresql

So I'm using postgresql 9.5 to store a bunch of data in a table named ids. The data is stored like this :

`id1 (UNIQUE, NOT NULL) | bool1 | bool2 | bool3 | id2 (not unique)`

id1 and id2 are text variables.
When I try to insert new data into the database I use this query :

`"INSERT INTO ids (id1, bool2, id2) VALUES (%s, TRUE, %s) ON CONFLICT (id1) DO UPDATE SET interaction = TRUE, id2 = %s;"`

Now when I try to insert this specific id1 : `c1316a6a-3bdd-4aeb-a1b6-b3044851880a__19`
 that is unique (I double checked that) the database hangs. While I am using python and psycopg2 to call the query, if I try to insert that key into the database by hand (by connecting to the database via CLI or GUI) the database still hangs.

However, if I create a similar database and use the exact same command, it works fine.

Any ideas as to why it hangs and how to fix it ?

EDIT :

Thank you, a_horse_with_no_name

It was indeed a waiting transaction. I killed its pid and everything worked fine afterwards.

Thanks again

Comment: Is `id1`  GUID or string?

Comment: id1 is a String variable, as it's not a standard UUID I believe. It has the UNIQUE and NOT NULL constraints

Comment: First: I'm pretty sure it's not the "database" that hangs, but only your transaction that is waiting. The reason for that is most likely that _another_ transaction also inserted that value but has not yet committed that. You can check `pg_stat_activity` if you have sessions with `waiting = true`

Comment: You're right :) How can i force a commit or a rollback on these transactions ?

Comment: You can kill a particular hanging transaction remotely with function `pg_cancel_backend(pid)` or terminate entire connection with `pg_terminate_backend(pid)`. You'll see the PID in `pg_stat_activity`.